# Doctirne query builder, filtering by birthday (working with DateTime)?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, doctrine-orm

I've a builder for selecting people with a phone number not `null`, a permission flag `true` (in the first builder call), and with a birthday template not `null` in this function. There is also a `birthday` field:

```
public function getAllForBirthdaySmsSend()
{
    $qb    = $this->getAllSuitableForSmsQueryBuilder();
    $alias = $qb->getRootAlias();
    $today = new \DateTime();

    return $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->isNotNull("$alias.sms_birthday_template"),
                /* Filter if today is his birthday */
            ))
    ;
}
```

Now i should filter people by birthday, that is if birthday column formatted as `'m-d-' . date('Y')` equals `$today`.

Anyone knows how to to this with query builder? I don't want to write pure SQL query but i prefer reusing the other query builder to be DRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native sql and then map it in order to deal with real entities makeing use og `ResultSetMapping`. Of curse, the YEAR is ignored:

Mapping the query fields:

```
$rsm = new Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

    $rsm->addEntityResult('models\User', 'u');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'username', 'username');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'birthday', 'birthday');
```

Create a query using native date functions (each selected column now is mapped ):

```
$query = $this->doctrine->em->createNativeQuery('
    SELECT id, username, birthday 
    FROM user 
    WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURRENT_DATE)
    > TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday, CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)', $rsm);
```

Get the users:

```
$users = $query->getResult();
```

**Tip**: Try to avoid casting column values when you want to do a query. It forces MySQL(if it is your case) to convert the column into a CHAR before performing the comparison and alter the performance.

**Edit** birthday column is datetime type. And the user model has the birtdate attibute mapped as `\DateTime object`

Comment: That's what i was doing without reading your answer! thanks! Just a question... `User` could be assigned to other entities? I mean... it's a "partial" object, would Doctrine complain about this?

Comment: The relation between objects is made by a reference column of this with other entities, while this values persist in the partial/proxy object should not be a problem.